# Trying to implement import-> debug mode module

Tags: python, debugging

So I am attempting to make a module that, when imported, will cause any exception to drop into pdb.  I'm thinking it will look something like this:

```
#file A.py
import pdbOnException

a = 1/0
print a

#file pdbOnException
import sys, pdb

magic_object = # do magic stuff to get an object that, when called, does what I want :D

try:
   magic_object()
except:
   tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
   pdb.post_mortem(tb)
```

Hopefully it is fairly obvious what I am trying to do.  I am trying to make it so that any module that imports this will have its unhandled exceptions go to pdb.

Edit: I thought I should add what I want to use this for, and see if you know anything about that.  I am planning on adding the module to eclipse's "Forced Builtins" so that eclipse will have this functionality (it is SORELY needed)
Can anyone help me out?

Edit2: after playing with eclipse a bunch, it looks like there is NO WAY to force eclipse to run a set of code (i.e. like PYTHONSTARTUP) prior to running any code.  Which sucks.  Therefore I think I will just go for the decorator.

If you still have an idea of how to do this by just importing modules, I am all ears.  It could be added to the IDLE startup script.

Update:
I just got something working using decorators, but the user has to call it for their main function (which isn't the end of the world... but I would like even more functionality).  Here it is:

```
def pdb_on_exception(function):
   def returnfunction(*args, **kwargs):
         try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
         except Exception as E:
            traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
            print E
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            pdb.post_mortem(tb)
   return returnfunction
```

This will drop you into pdb if there is an unhandled exception on the function that is being decorated.  Which is cool but still not what I want :D

Comment: Similar to your decorator, you could also devise a context manager that does this. I don't see any way to make it reach out and affect the importing module though - you would need to modify Eclipse to wrap the execution of all imported modules with your new context manager.

Comment: I wish I knew how to modify eclipse to do this...  I'm doing another update with more of my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty trivial, you just hook into sys.excepthook:

fullofeels.py:

```
import sys, pdb

def except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    if previous_except_hook:
        previous_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback)

    pdb.post_mortem(traceback)

previous_except_hook = sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = except_hook
```

Usage:

Normally we just get a traceback:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

But import fullofeels, and we fall into pdb:

```
>>> import fullofeels
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
> <stdin>(1)<module>()
(Pdb)
```

Tada!

I have no idea how many eels are in that hovercraft, but for simple cases it works.

Comment: It's only easy if you know about excepthook!  Thanks a ton!  (I can't upvote yet, but I WILL as soon as I can)

Comment: Oh, very nice - I didn't even think about `excepthook`, since I was looking at it from an executing-a-script point of view, rather than an interactive-prompt one.

Comment: @Garrett: since you asked the question, you should have an "Accept Answer" button that you can click.

Comment: Since I couldn't vote before, it didn't pop up, but it just did when I voted.  Answer accepted, thanks :D